# Is there a way to plot two graphs at once using matplotlib in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, enumerate

I'm trying to simulate the following systems of chemical reactions over time, calculating and plotting how the numbers of each molecule type changes over time:

```
1S + 0T + 0U --> 0S + 0T + 0U
2S + 0T + 0U --> 0S + 1T + 0U 
0S + 1T + 0U --> 2S + 0T + 0U
0S + 1T + 0U --> 0S + 0T + 1U
```

Because S is used in two reactions, being consumed in one and produced in another it kind of skews the results when I plot them. At the moment the code I've got to do the plotting is as follows:

```
for i, label in enumerate(['S', 'T', 'U']):
    plt.plot(popul_num_all[:, i], label=label)
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

That produces the following plot
[image]

This plot is created from the elements of an array: `popul_num = np.array([S, T, U])` where I've used iteration to update and store the new values of molecule numbers over time

But the line for S just looks especially bad, Is there a way to separate the lines of S being plotted on one graph, and then the lines of T and U being plotted on a second?

Would the easiest way be to just write two enumerate functions one for S and a second for T and U ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try subplots

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

ax1.plot(popul_num_all[:, 0], label='S')
ax1.legend()

for i, label in enumerate(['T', 'U']):
    ax2.plot(popul_num_all[:, i+1], label=label)

ax2.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```